Firewall software that will filter youtube categories
I am using m2 macbook with Sequoia. Looking for a 7th layer virtual firewall that can be configured on my mac which will filter out youtube based on the video category id. Any ideas with what or how I can achieve this? Should I use proxy instead? Any recommendations? Thanks.
I know that with fortinet physical firewall you can achieve this:
https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-How-to-restrict-the-YouTube-video-categories-to/ta-p/340906
However, I wish to find out a virtual solution for my home Macbook.
